# Detect location of certain element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have three buttons in a row, with the end one being a 'deadly' button. Is there a way I can click on button 1, and it would tell me that it's 2 elements away from the 'deadly' button?
Or click on button 2, which would tell me it's once space away from number 3, the 'deadly' button.

I'm not sure I've explained this very well, so I'll link an example of the setup.

I'm hoping do something similar to the Minesweeper way of detecting the 'mines'.

### HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><button id="1">Button 1</button></td>
        <td><button id="2">Button 2</button></td>
        <td><button id="3">Button 3</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><button id="4">Button 4</button></td>
        <td><button id="deadly">Button 5</button></td>
        <td><button id="6">Button 6</button></td>
    </tr>  
    <tr>
        <td><button id="7">Button 7</button></td>
        <td><button id="8">Button 8</button></td>
        <td><button id="9">Button 9</button></td>
    </tr> 
</table>
```

I'm currently using JQuery, so any solution that uses it will still work for me.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/m2u0je4j/)

Comment: I'd suggest using something like this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jonathan_Ironman/J6JCF/)

Comment: @SterlingArcher to create the Minefield, instead of tables and buttons...

Comment: Oh, I thought that fiddle somehow answered the detection question. Didn't realize you were advertising a map builder.

Comment: But, just a note, MineSweeper tells you how many 'deadly things' are in the cells surrounding the one you clicked; *not* how far away the 'deadly things' are...

Comment: This second [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jonathan_Ironman/TBMPW/2/) would be a decent starting point for a Minesweeper game I guess.

Comment: If I'm honest, I've never really played Minesweeper. It just seemed the closest to what I'm trying to attempt :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At its simplest, you can use the `cellIndex` property of the `<td>` element within which the `<button>` is enclosed:

```
$('button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var self = $(this),
        cellIndex = self.closest('td').prop('cellIndex'),
        lastCell = self.closest('tr').find('td:last-child').prop('cellIndex'),
        delta = Math.abs(lastCell - cellIndex);
    console.log( delta + (delta === 1 ? ' cell' : ' cells') + ' away from deadly cell');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/m2u0je4j/5/).

References:

- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Comment: This solution is the one I understand better, but (after I tweaked it to see what was where) I found that it shows all of the last column as deadly (http://puu.sh/cOlGz/5ae955c715.png) any advice to fix this?

Comment: But isn't that what you said: "*I have three buttons in a row, with the end one being a 'deadly' button*"? What result do you want if I click on button4, and button9?

Comment: This is all just for an example, but I appreciate your help. If the 'deadly' button was, say, button 6, 4 would say 2 cells and 9 would say 1, as they are varying lengths away.

Comment: And button1 would be 2 horizontally, and 1 vertically; so...you'd want the (sort of) hypotenuse distance of 2 cells away? Or just the largest number (horizontal or vertical; in the above case that's obviously the same distance)?

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
$("button").click(function() {
    var myrow = $(this).parent().index();
    var mycol = $(this).index();
    var deadly = $("#deadly");
    var deadly_row = deadly.parent().index();
    var deadly_col = deadly.index();
    var x_dist = Math.abs(mycol - deadly_col);
    var y_dist = Math.abs(myrow - deadly_row);
    // Do what you want with x_dist and y_dist
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This code randomly determines the deadly square and then checks onclick.  First it check the coordinates to see if they match, if not then it determines the distance.  Here I simply pass coordinates with the function call.  you can dynamicallygrow your table if you want to.  The added benefit of this approach is that you cannot just view the source and find out which button holds the "deadly"

```
<script>
    var DeadlyX = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
    var DeadlyY = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);


    function amIDeadly(x, y) {

        var r = "checking";
        if ((x == DeadlyX) && (y == DeadlyY)) {
            r = "found the deadly!";
        }
        else {
            var dx = x - DeadlyX;
            var dy = y - DeadlyY;
            var hyp = dx*dx + dy*dy;
            hyp = Math.sqrt(hyp);
            hyp = Math.floor(hyp);
            r = "you are " + hyp + " from the deadly";
        }
        document.getElementById("infobox").value = r;

    }
</script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button id="1" onclick="amIDeadly(1,1);">Button 1</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button id="2" onclick="amIDeadly(1,2);">Button 2</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button id="3" onclick="amIDeadly(1,3);">Button 3</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button id="4" onclick="amIDeadly(2,1);">Button 4</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button id="5" onclick="amIDeadly(2,2);">Button 5</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button id="6" onclick="amIDeadly(2,3);">Button 6</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button id="7" onclick="amIDeadly(3,1);">Button 7</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button id="8" onclick="amIDeadly(3,2);">Button 8</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button id="9" onclick="amIDeadly(3,3);">Button 9</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br/>
<br/>
<input id="infobox" />
```